# How do I package addtional static web resource in Quarkus app?

Tags: quarkus

In my pom.xml in the compile phase I generate static html content under target/web-resources/...

How do I package these files in the target jar under META-INF/resources ?

Comment: This actually won't play well with how Quarkus handles them. Mind opening a new issue so we can discuss how to handle it?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I consider to open this requirement as an issue. BTW is this better to achieve with gradle (currently I know very little about gradle)?

Comment: @geoand - I just created https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/36437

Comment: Meanwhile I managed to find an intermediate solution. Writing the files in target/classes/META-INF/classes did the trick. Though I bypassed all quarkus resource management I can build the target jar that I needed. Anyway - a direct support from quarkus maven plugin is highly appreciated.